# Does the Feel language builtin string function 'replace' affect the first match or all occurrances of the search pattern?

Tags: dmn, feel-language

The Decision Model and Notation Feel Language has many builtin functions.
For strings, one function is `replace`. It accepts a search string, a regex pattern, a replacement string, and optional flags.

Does `replace` act only on the first regex match or does it replace all matches? The DMN version 1.3 specification, page 138, does not seem to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, it replaces all matches.

Some other valid examples:

```
replace("banana","a","o") = "bonono"
```

taken as one of the [agreed behaviour test cases](https://github.com/dmn-tck/tck/blob/master/TestCases/compliance-level-3/0002-string-functions/0002-string-functions.pdf), from the DMN TCK project.

I agree in the DMN Specification document from OMG, it could list some more down-to-Earth examples :)

Comment: FYI, I've noted to the OMG DMN RTF to add some basic example in the spec too: https://issues.omg.org/browse/INBOX-1179